# Set users to isFrozen through Apex gives error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, You cannot edit this field

Tags: apex

I've searching options to set my users `isFrozen = true`, which I found here, but after trying it I got a weird error:

```
List<UserLogin> users = [SELECT Id,IsFrozen,UserId FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId IN
(SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name != 'System Administrator' AND IsActive = true)
AND UserId != :UserInfo.getUserId()];

users[0].IsFrozen = true;

update users;
```

I don't get why, but its giving me:

`System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0Yw29000001XZqMCAW; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, You cannot edit this field: []`

Am I mistaken in something related to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized, doing some debugging that when it was going through all the Users, it was breaking on a user with a different license type. So limiting to `Salesforce` type of license made it work.

So this piece of code, works perfectly:

```
public static void freezeUsers(){

    List<UserLogin> users = [SELECT Id,IsFrozen,UserId FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId IN
                        (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name != 'System Administrator'
                        AND IsActive = true AND Profile.UserLicense.Name = 'Salesforce')
                        AND UserId != :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    if(users != null && !users.isEmpty()){
        for (UserLogin ul : users) {
            System.debug('User Login: ' + ul);
            ul.IsFrozen = true;
        }
        try {
            update(users);
        } catch (DmlException ex) {
            System.debug('Exception: ' + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The change was specifically in the query: `Profile.UserLicense.Name = 'Salesforce'`.

Comment: You can update userlogin of other UserLicense too.

Comment: For anyone coming here looking for what's going on:

This query is likely picking up users such as the Automated Process user or some other users that cannot be frozen. These users have a profile with no name and no license, which is why when we put the license filter we no longer see the problem.

It might be best for your implementation to use a filter to only freeze users that have specific profiles or some other filter to identify your production users and leave out other users.

Answer (score 0):

**UserLogin**

> Represents the settings that affect a user’s ability to log into an
>   organization. To access this object, you need the
>   UserPermissions.ManageUsers permission. This object is available in
>   API version 29.0 and later.

Everything else looks fine in your code and even it worked, maybe you have not the appropriate access as mentioned above. Make sure you have **UserPermissions.ManageUsers permission**.

**Note:- You can update userlogin without keeping any concern on license.**